# vue-gapi Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '$gapi')

Tags: vue.js, google-api

I'm trying to install this library `https://github.com/vue-gapi/vue-gapi/tree/releases/v1` into my vue2 project, so I just did exactly what the page asked me to do. So after running `npm install --save vue-gapi` I added

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueGapi from 'vue-gapi'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueGapi, {
  apiKey: 'myapikey',
  clientId: 'myclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  discoveryDocs: ['https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4'],
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

But I will receive this error

```
vue-gapi.common.js?8dd9:478 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '$gapi')
    at Object.install (vue-gapi.common.js?8dd9:478)
    at Function.Vue.use (vue.esm.js?efeb:5130)
    at eval (main.js?1c90:18)
    at Object../src/main.js (app.js:2230)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at fn (app.js:89)
    at Object.0 (app.js:2247)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at app.js:725
    at app.js:728
```

Further clicking at `Object.install (vue-gapi.common.js?8dd9:478)` will show me this error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be seen that `vue-gapi.common.js` contains Vue 3 code, likely because the latest version has been installed, this results in an error.

Considering that 1.x support Vue 2, it should be:

```
npm install --save vue-gapi@1
```

Comment: aha! This does it, thanks!